# Duda sobre multiplicar elementos de una lista

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en Codecademy, específicamente este: 
[Modificar cada elemento de una lista en una función](https://www.codecademy.com/es/courses/python-beginner-en-hsood/3/2?curriculum_id=53a32847fed2a88075000001#)

El caso, que el código que estoy intentando usar es este:

```
n = [3, 5, 7]
def doble_lista(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
    x[i]=x[i]*2
    return x

print doble_lista(n)
```

Y siempre me sale el mismo error:

```
File "python", line 5
    x[i]=x[i]*2
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Ya he probado a reescribir el código completamente, he preguntado en los foros oficiales de la página y no han sabido responderme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python reconoce los bloques de código por su nivel de indentado, de hecho, el mismo interprete te dice el error `IndentationError` en la línea 5.

Como tienes el código actualmente, dudo que vaya a ejecutarse, puesto que luego de cada `:` al escribir una sentencia, Python espera un nivel de indentación diferente que el que contiene la linea con `:`, me explico:

Este es tu código actual:

```
n = [3, 5, 7]
def doble_lista(x):
for i in range(0, len(x)):
x[i]=x[i]*2
return x

print doble_lista(n)
```

Indentado finalmente quedaría así:

```
n = [3, 5, 7]
def doble_lista(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i]=x[i]*2
    return x

print doble_lista(n)
```

Este útimo, funciona bien.

Yendo un poco mas profundo, ¿Por qué pasa esto? Como he dicho anteriormente, Python reconoce los niveles de indentación como bloques de código, ejemplo:

```
def DiHola():
print "Hola"
```

No funciona como esperamos, porque la definición del método `DiHola()` está al mismo nivel que el `print`, lo correcto es indentar aunque sea por un espacio, para definir el bloque de código:

```
def DiHola():
  print "Hola"
```

Entonces, mientras más bloques tenemos, tenemos que indentar:

```
def EjecutaAlgo():
    nombre = "NaCl"   # Todas las lineas que no aplican un bloque de indentado
    for s in nombre:  # van al mismo nivel, ejemplo estas dos.
        print s
```

Y así sucesivamente, todo esto está en las guias de programación de Python [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).